# Print array in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

I need to check my values from `NSArray` which are stored dynamically. How should I print the array values in Objective-C?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/992901/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-nsarray

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@",yourArray);
```

This actually calls the description method of your NSArray and prints it to the log.
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/description

Comment: And the description method of each object in it.

Comment: Note that the `description` is intended for debugging use only.  Don't use it as something you want to store and parse later.