# retrieving string from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on the following function:

```
-(void)logResults:(NSDictionary *)results {
    NSMutableString *logString = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    for (NSString *key in results) {
        if([key isEqualToString:@"index"]){
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[results objectForKey:key]];
            string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""];
            [results setValue:string forKey:key];
        }
        NSLog(@"KEY: %@, VALUE: %@", key, [results objectForKey:key]);
        [logString appendFormat:@"|%@ = %@ \n", key, [results objectForKey:key]];
    }
    self.logInfo.text = [logString stringByAppendingString:self.logInfo.text];
}
```

problem lies within the if, I get the following error: `[_NSArrayM length] unrecognised sel...`

I was first attempting to use following expression for the if's work:

```
//[results setValue:[((NSString *)[results objectForKey:key]) stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@""] forKey:@"index"];
```

which resulted in:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]

Comment: `string` might be a `NSArray` hence the `[__NSArrayM stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]`. Check to see if `string` actually is getting the string that you want.

Comment: @user1813076 it is. the line: [logString appendFormat:@"|%@ = %@ \n", key, [results objectForKey:key]]; has been working fine. I am only doing this to trim a string i was already getting properly. btw, even the initial NSString *string = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[results objectForKey:key]]; crashes, which i find very weird since the first-mentioned expression (in this comment) works, and they are both treating strings. I did also try to make a cast to NSString

Comment: At what line exactly does it crash and what is the exact error message for the code block?

Comment: @DevilInDisguise please show your NSDictionary data, it problem about you are fetch wrong way data from it.

Comment: @luk2303  NSMutableString *string = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:(NSString *)[results objectForKey:key]];   this initial line causes a crash. Referring to me above comment I think this is weird as a latter expression works.  ERROR: erminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x17005ffb0'

Comment: Add inside your if an additional if, something like `if ([[results objectForKey:key] isKindOfClass [NSString class]]) {}` and some NSLog into `else` statement to see if it's really NSString.

Comment: @teamnorge [logString appendFormat:@"|%@ = %@ \n", key, [results objectForKey:key]] would not execute if it wasn't a string.

Comment: also `[logString appendFormat:@"|%@ = %@ \n", key, [results objectForKey:key]]` still executes if it wasn't a string. Short description why is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396336/print-array-in-objective-c)

Comment: @DevilInDisguise, you could also check if your `[key isKindOfClass [NSString class]]` before comparing is it is equal to `@"index"`.

Comment: @user1813076 you are right. can i check the specific class without testing isMemberOfClass, conformsToProtocol on different types?

Comment: @teamnorge the if returns 1 as it is

Comment: @user1813076 u should post that as an answer, valueForKey or objectForKey both works(don't know the difference rly). Does it make sense that you are allowed to assign nsstring instances non-string types? this is what got me

Comment: @DevilInDisguise one more thing I did not noticed initially, your `results` is of type `(NSDictionary *)` not `(NSMutableDictionary *)` and you attempt to setValue on non mutable object.

Comment: @teamnorge [setValue forKey:] is available for NSDictionary, at least pops up as suggestion in Xcode.. I got what i wanted another way now, but thx for your input. Amazing how someone just down voted myq uestion just now... ppl are funny lol. cheers

Comment: why did i just get a down vote to this?.........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `[results objectForKey:key]];` is returning an array which is causing all of your crashes. To create a `NSString` from the array use `[results valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@""];`

Comment: so it turned out that the json i was parsing into a string, thinking it was a string, I could just handle the objects and arrays instead of doing string analysing lol.... thx for the help!