# Sorting Array based on numbers

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am having an array that contains the values like 2,4,6 etc .Now I want to sort array to find the maximum value,I do not know how to do that.
Please Help me.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You don't need to sort an array to find the maximum value!

Comment: @Jen - I suggest using a Quick Sort Algorithm.

Comment: You need to give more info in your question. What sort of array? A plain C style array? Objective C style array? Is this homework btw?

Comment: @Ramhound Why use quicksort to find the maximum value? It'll take n log n time. Just scanning the array is linear n time.

Comment: NSSortDescriptor *mySorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"floatValue" ascending:NO];
 [listItems sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:mySorter]];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSinteger biggest = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
for(int i=1; i<[yourArray count]; i++) {
    NSinteger current = [[yourArray objectAtIndex:i] integerValue];
    if(current >= biggest) {
        biggest = current;
    }
}
```

this will give you the biggest element in the array.

**UPDATE**

As @occculus suggested you can try fast enumeration. Here is a reference [How do I iterate over an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992901/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-nsarray)

**FIX**

Your code was both wrong (as reported by Kalle) and inefficient (redundant calls of `objectAtIndex:`). Fixed it, hope you don't mind.
Regexident

Comment: Using a fast enumeration would be better.

Comment: You can't store ints in an array. They are either NSStrings or NSNumbers. In either case you have to add "intValue" to the [yourArray...] calls.

Comment: @Kalle fixed it. Some birdie tells me Jenifer didn't even test it prior to accepting. :P

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the highest value by looking at each value only once.

```
int highest = INT_MIN;

for (id elem in array)
{
    int current = [elem intValue];
    if (highest < current)
        highest = current;
}
```

If you want the array to be sorted anyway:

```
NSArray *sorted = [unsorted sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

int highest = [[sorted lastObject] intValue];
```