# How to print NSArray objects via for statement or enumeration?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, for-loop, nsarray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I iterate over an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992901/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-nsarray)

Here is my code (for example):

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Red", @"Blue", @"Green", nil];
```

I want loop through the array printing each string to the console.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's find the most complex way, shall we?

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray array];
id *objects = malloc(sizeof(id) * myArray.count);
[myArray getObjects:objects range:NSMakeRange(0, myArray.count)];

char **strings = malloc(sizeof(char *) * myArray.count);

for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++)
{
     strings[i] = [objects[i] UTF8String];
}

printf("<");
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.count; i++)
{
     printf("%s" strings[i]);
     if (i != myArray.count - 1)
         printf(", ");
}
printf(">");

free(objects);
free(strings);
```

Of course, you can always just do it like this:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

Comment: How was this accepted? I was just being a smart-ass

Comment: Quite impressive. I am missing some bit-shifting…

Comment: Or direct bit-manipulation on the RAM chip by focussing the sun's rays onto the relevant memory cells with a magnifying glass

Comment: Or someone could have answered his actual question and suggested: printf ("%s\n", [[a componentsJoinedByString: @"|"] cString]);

Answer (score 28):

The easiest way is just:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

Or, if you want to use fast enumeration to print each object in your own way:

```
for (NSString *string in myArray) {
    NSLog(@"%@", string);
}
```