# How to implement Fast enumeration on this code

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to implement fast `enumeration` on this code, please help me.

```
int xx;
int b=0;

for (xx=0 ; xx<(distancearray.count); xx++) {
    if ([NSNull null]!=[distancearray objectAtIndex:xx]&& 0 !=[[[distancearray objectAtIndex:xx] description] intValue] ) {
        b++;
        latitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",b*100];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
for( id object in distancearray){
    if ([NSNull null]!=object && 0 !=[[object description] intValue] ) {
        b++;
        latitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",b*100];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity sake:

```
for( id object in distancearray){
    if (object && [[object description] intValue] != 0) {
        b++;
        latitudeLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %d",b*100];
    }
}
```

To know about iterating an array:[How do I iterate over an NSArray?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992901/how-do-i-iterate-over-an-nsarray)