# Run code For each element of an array

Tags: ios, soap, nsarray

i have the following code

```
 DownloadOperations *DataObj=[[DownloadOperations alloc]init];
[DataObj ID];

NSString *body=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'><soap:Body><GetDocumentUpdatedInfo xmlns='http://tempuri.org/'><DocumentID>%@</DocumentID></GetDocumentUpdatedInfo></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>", [DataObj ID]];
NSLog(@"Body %@", body);
```

in this code `[DataObj ID]` is an `NsMutablearray` and the `NSString` (body) is the `soap Request` which requires a `string` value. how can i get this `soap request` to run iterativly for each element of the `array`?

Comment: The same way you loop over an array for anything else.  Do you know how to do `for` loops?

Comment: I do but what will the condition be ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/992913/1155387 (Note you don't have to use `id` you can just substitute `NSString *`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int loopCount = 0;
while (loopCount < [[DataObj ID] count]){
    //Do stuff with [[DataObj ID] objectAtIndex:loopCount]
    loopCount++;
}
```