# iOS replaceObjectAtIndex Error

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am new to iOS development, I encounter error when replaceObjectAtIndex. Any wrong with my codes? Please help.Thanks.

```
self.myArray =array;
for (NSDictionary *data in array) {
NSString *fbid = [data objectForKey:@"id"];

for (int index = 0; index < self.myPersonArray.count; index ++) {

    for (IP_PERSON *person in self.myPersonArray) {
        if ([person.UserDef2 isEqualToString:fbid]) {
            [self.myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:person];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Error is : 
Terminating app due to uncaught exception `NSGenericException`, reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0xa34f6c0> was mutated while being enumerated.

Comment: Don't make us play games to get information.  **WHAT IS THE ERROR**?  My guess is that it is *unrecognized selector*.

Comment: Collection NSArray was mutated while being enumerated

Answer (score 3):

You cannot use *fast enumeration* and mutate collection at the same time, hence the error message. You can resort to using an usual for-loop.

Comment: Sorry new here,Any example to refer.Thanks

Comment: Consider an example in this answer, the whole discussion is great too, http://stackoverflow.com/a/992910/7437

Comment: am i missing something here? he *is* using the usual for loop, i don't see any fast enumeration..

Comment: @abbood `self.myArray =array;
for (NSDictionary *data in array)`

Comment: @DmitryShevchenko oh so that's the same as doing an enumerate object with block etc.. good to know..

Comment: @abbood yep, this form is the *original* fast enumeration, block way just wraps around it.

Answer (score 0):

You're iterating over `array`, which is equal to `self.myArray`.

Further down, you're editing this array when you do:  `[self.myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:person];`

To resolve this, just make `self.array` a mutableCopy of the original array:

```
self.myArray = [array mutableCopy];
```

Comment: Hi ggmathur, When I change to self.myArray = [array mutableCopy], I get the endless result.Do you know why ? Thanks Eg.1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234,1234....

Answer (score 0):

You can take another temporary array and iterate over that array, so you are enumerating and mutating different array.

> ```
> NSArray *tempArray = [yourArray copy];
> for (IP_PERSON *person in tempArray) {
>     if ([person.UserDef2 isEqualToString:fbid]) {
>         [self.myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:index withObject:person];
>         break;
>    }
> }
> [tempArray release];
> ```

Alternatively you can iterate without an enumerator, you can use regular for loop with starting index, exit condition and increment as you have done in outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

You can..

```
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary]
self.myArray =array;
for (NSDictionary *data in array) {
NSString *fbid = [data objectForKey:@"id"];

                    for (int index = 0; index < self.myPersonArray.count; index ++) {

                        for (IP_PERSON *person in self.myPersonArray) {
                            if ([person.UserDef2 isEqualToString:fbid]) {
                                    [dictionary setObject:person forKey:@(index)]; //Notice this line
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

And then..

```
for(id key in dictionary) {
  [self.myArray replaceObjectAtIndex:[key intValue] withObject:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
}
```

Comment: Hi Syed Absar, I following your code but I get the following error No visible @interface for 'NSMutableDictionary' declares the selector 'addObject:forKey:'

Comment: Sorry, it is setObject and not addObject.